# "Mail" command hangs and maillogs shows error

Tags: email

i tried linux command on my CentOS 5.x:

mail -s "mysubject" mymail@gmail.com

minutes takes, it dont finish, i do Ctrl+C, it says "(Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)"

i tried command:

mail

No mail for root

/var/log/maillog is empty

/var/log/kloxo/maillog is full of messages:

Oct 25 17:28:17 vps qmail: 1382736497.255902 delivery 1246425: **deferral: Uh-oh:_.qmail_has_prog_delivery_but_has_x_bit_set._**(#4.7.0)/
Oct 25 17:28:17 vps qmail: 1382736497.255915 status: local 1/10 remote 0/60

i checked all my .qmail files and none has execution permissions. Any idea please how to debug?

Comment: From the `mail` manpage: To send a message to one or more people, mailx can be invoked with arguments which are the names of people to whom the mail will be sent.  **The user is then expected to type in his message, followed by an 'control-D' at the beginning of a line.**

Answer (score 6):

That command takes the mail data on `stdin`. Try the following:

```
echo "this is the mail body" | mail -s "mysubject" mymail@gmail.com
```

Comment: thx, it worked. it really needed message text this way.

Comment: work as a charm

Comment: That still hangs for me.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are invoking the command assumes you are composing an email on the fly.   After you hit enter, the program is waiting for you to compose the message, which you end by putting a single "." character.

Try this:

```
mail -s "mysubject" mymail@gmail.com
Type some stuff here that you want to mail.
Some more stuff.
The last stuff.
.<enter>
```

Comment: @harmony excellent. Please upvote and mark as "accepted" whatever answer you deem worthy. Thanks!